# Export multi project with difference resource by gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project, now I want to export to multi project with difference resource by gradle. Anyone can show me some ideas?

Comment: I guess  you working in android studio?

Comment: yes, i'm working in Android Studio. Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by [Product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)

> A product flavor defines a customized version of the application build by the project. A single project can have different flavors which change the generated application.

From [Sourcesets and Dependencies](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies)

> Similar to Build Types, Product Flavors also contribute code and
>   resources through their own sourceSets.
>
> The above example creates four sourceSets:
>
> ```
> android.sourceSets.flavor1
> Location src/flavor1/
> android.sourceSets.flavor2
> Location src/flavor2/
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Android studio to open multiple Projects in same Frame. However you can open multiple frames at a same time.

But you can add new Module or Library for your project which can be shown in same Window. Module Can be added as:

File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies

Then add the module (android library) as a module dependency.

Comment: I mean how can i build from an android project to 2,3 application with different resource (ex: app icon, app name, ...). Not open multi project in the same Frame.

Comment: didn't get you. What you actually want